How to use ng-bootstrap with Angular 18
I just updated my angular app to Angular 18 and now seems that there is no compatible version of ng-bootstrap for angular 18?
While resolving: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0
npm error Found: @angular/common@18.0.6
npm error node_modules/@angular/common
npm error   @angular/common@"18.0.6" from the root project
npm error   peer @angular/common@"^18.0.0 || ^19.0.0" from @angular/cdk@18.0.6
npm error   node_modules/@angular/cdk
....
Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer @angular/common@"^17.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0
npm error node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm error   @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"16.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@17.3.11
npm error node_modules/@angular/common
npm error   peer @angular/common@"^17.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0
npm error   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm error     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"16.0.0" from the root project

I have a nx workspace with more than three apps and some libs. Any idea how to handle it in a best way?

Have you tried update @ng-bootstrap to version 17.0? https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/releases/tag/17.0.0

@YongShun checked their website  seems that they support until angular 17 !!

It seems like they didn't update in NPM website, but if you read their repository, README, supports Angular 18 with version 17. https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

According to Angular Powered Bootstrap Documentation
Angular ^18.0.0 
ng-bootstrap 17.x.x
Bootstrap CSS 5.3.2 
Popper ^2.11.8

